# Diode voltage for small signal model what is the small signal component v_d

Tags: diodes, circuits, diode-clamp

What is the small signal component v_d in this graph? Since they say \$V_D = v_D + v_d \$ [image]

Comment: Someone drew that graph, why not ask that person?

Comment: cause this is from a video lecture a while back

Comment: so, ask your professor, or re-watch the lecture? How are we, who haven't even watched that lecture, supposed to know better than you what's on that blackboard?

Answer (score 1):

The small signal component $$v_d$$ is the small AC voltage varying around the larger DC component (bias) of the diode.

See: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small-signal_model